# Prevent XMLSerializer from writing invalid characters

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

Some of my users, lord only knows how (I haven't figured that out yet) are inputting vertical tabs `xB` `\V` or however else they're doing it.  The code doesn't care, and neither does the XMLSerializer, however when I try to open the resulting XML it treats it as malformed xml because the character `&#xB;` is invalid.

I can catch this at a per field level during validation events, simply filter out `\v` during the validation, manually replace it with empty string.  But there are potentially several THOUSAND manually entered text fields in a given client file.  It would be really nice not to have to block off every single text entry validation event in the entire code base with that validation.

So: Is there a way to prevent XMLSerializer from writing this character?  Some manner of building it, or setting some setting somewhere, or even providing it a set of customized writing rules (is that even possible?)  That would be great.

Comment: Amusingly, I open it in the same program that serialized it.  It wont re-open it, which is why I want to try and stop it from writing the invalid characters in the first place.  C# Application, opened using a memory stream which is being fed to an XMLSerializer to de-serialize it back into the same object it was generated from.

Comment: Just checked, the DataContractSerializer will round-trip the #xB without complaining. So if you can handle the [DataMember] fluf...